# How to load local JSON file into java-script without jquery

Tags: javascript, json

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question, but I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer.

I need to find a way to import a javascipt JSON file from a local file-system without using any Jquery libraries, or server-side features.

I am creating a power shell script in which I export a few objects as JSONs. I want to then take that object and import it into a local htm report with javasscript. This means that it will be ran and read locally, without having any server side components at all. I also cannot use JQuery or any other external scripts, since I want all of this to be self contained and written on execution of my powershell script...

I've tried this :

```
function loadJSON(path, success, error)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (success)
                    success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                if (error)
                    error(xhr);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

loadJSON('./test.js',
         function(data) { console.log(data); },
         function(xhr) { console.error(xhr); }
);
```

But, of course this fails with an error stating that XMLHttpRequest can only be used as a server http request, not as a local file-request.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: AJAX only works from a server.

Comment: Correct, which is why I asked this question. :)

Comment: You need to run it from a server, no way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just read the file line by line using simple file handling of javascript and then parse it as JSON using JSON parser.. Or else through your code i can see that your JSON is not actually stored in a .json file rather its stored in an .js file, so if its like

Sample code of test.js

```
var a = [
{
...
},
{
...
}
];
```

Then you can include it as a simple js file like you include any other js file and then use the 'a' var directly.